# Normalizing a list of values between a range

Tags: python, normalize

So let's say I have something like this:

```
values = [10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0]
```

I basically want to multiply everything in the list by a power of 2, but then normalize it back down to range it was in.

This is how I was attempting to do it, but not getting the results I expected.

```
minVal = min(values)
maxVal = max(values)

normValues = [((q**2)-minVal)/(maxVal - minVal) for q in values]
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: please post your expected result and the result you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly possible that when you square each value in your list and normalize them back, you cannot get them back in the same range. 
For example : if you take `[2, 3, 5]`.
After squaring, you will get `[4, 9, 25]`.
You can normalize this in a way such that the range is between 0 to 1 i.e you divide all the elements by the largest value getting `[0.16, 0.36, 1]`.
I don't think this list can be scaled back such that the range becomes the same as before.
Correct me if I'm wrong.